# How to create a font with precise character height in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, font-size

In my program I need to generate a bitmap with all digit characters (0..9) laid from left to right, plus a few other characters.

The user will select from the UI:

1. the desired font, and
2. the desired character height in pixels.

So I want to create a Bitmap, then a Graphics from this bitmap, then draw the digits one by one to this bitmap, and then save it to disk.

What I couldn't figure out in hours:
How do I create a font with the correct size so that the digit '0' has the height given by the user?

I played with all the parameters in the Font constructor, with properties of StringFormat, with MeasureString/MeasureText/MeasureCharacterRanges, I tried creating the font with the native CreateFont() via P/Invoke (with positive/negative nHeight). All parameters called "size" or "height" seem to indicate the size of some hypothetical character that's much larger than '0'.

I did read the theory with line height, em height, ascent, descent etc. There seem to be no notion for the *real* height of a character, without padding and spacing and so on

Again my question: Given the font name and the desired pixel height for the '0' glyph, how can I create a font which draws that glyph with the required height?

I would appreciate any guidance.

LATER EDIT
Some more details about my project: It's an embedded device with a big display, and I need to provide an easy way for the designers to to generate and try out bitmap fonts of their liking. A Windows tool that generates such bitmap fonts seemed like a good solution to me.

Comment: GDI+ based text measurements are a bit weird. Look into plain GDI APIs. Some other questions about centering text vertically might be helpful.

Comment: The system font system will always reserve space for abnormally high or low characters.  Why not try a "test-and-resolve" loop?  Print the character zero, and measure its height in pixels programmatically - e.g. check to make sure at least ten rows of pixels horizontally have at least one bit set.  Then increase the size of the font by one if it fails and try again until it succeeds.  You'd unfortunately have to then crop off the unused rows of pixels since there will be some overlap.

Comment: Yeah, I had in mind something like this, but I'd like to keep that as a last resort solution. I was looking at the stupid Paint program that somehow manages to do exactly what I need (I tell it "Arial 10" and it draws text exactly 10-pixel high) and I was hoping there's a clear programatical way to do that...

Answer (score 1):

While I wasn't far off the mark with what I posted here earlier, it didn't actually work. In banging my head against this I found it interesting to note that graphics.MeasureString("M", ...) reports a height far larger than graphics.MeasureString("MM", ...). In calculating the font sizes by hand I've found the first(which correlates with GetEMSize's response) is actually the full line size. In the end I came to realize the actual character sizes of the digits aren't required to correlate to any of the metrics, whether real or .net.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use this [Font Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8dy0032.aspx) to specify the [GraphicsUnit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphicsunit.aspx) to be pixels. Then it should create the font with the appropriate size.

Adding test code - edit accordingly for your case and don't judge for style, I just wanted something I could paste in LINQPad and would produce an image.

```
using (var font = new Font("Arial",10,FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
using (var image = new Bitmap(30, 15))
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, 30, 15));
    graphics.DrawString("Ay", font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
    image.Save(@"E:\test.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

Remember when setting size by Pixels that all characters in the Font need to fit in that range, meaning letters with a descender and letters with an ascender.

Comment: This is one of the first things I tried.
I've just tested it again: from Arial 10 I get a '0' that's 7 pixels high.

Comment: This does work as expected. You just tried an A, do an `A` and a `y` and you will see that the total height for the line is 10.

Comment: Thanks for the sample, but it's not what I need. What I need is in the initial question. I'll write it here another way: How do I calculate the size passed to the Font() constructor so that the glyph '0' (NOT the string "Ay") of a given font has a given height?

Some more details about my project: It's an embedded device with a big display, and I need to provide an easy way for the designers to to generate and try out bitmap fonts of their liking. A Windows tool that generates such bitmaps seemed like a good solution to me.